# I am unable to access the webelement without using the find_elements

Tags: python, selenium

```
paymentNumber = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id="search"]') 
paymentNumber.send_keys(check_number)
```

but as it returns a list I am unable to send values to the textbox. Already tried with `find_element_by_xpath('')`, it just crashes by raising exception:raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace):cant locate the webelement

> Error:   File
>
> line 53, in downloadFile
>       paymentNumber.send_keys(check_number) AttributeError: ("'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'", u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Share the relevant html.

Comment: Did you really try `driver.find_element_by_xpath('')` ? You should use `driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="search"]')` to get the first matching element or iterate over the list, if you want to send text to all matching elements.

Comment: Hi, I actually have tried it, but some how the script crashes with an error message that it cannot locate the webelement

Comment: But when i use elements, it goes to the next line which is send_keys() and crashes there- i understand the reason that find_elements returns a list, so i tried payementNumber[0].send_keys(), that too doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Given that you use the same Xpath expression it is hard to believe that

```
find_element_by_xpath
```

behaves differently than

```
find_elements_by_xpath
```

Most probably, the **Xpath expression is wrong and no element is found**. With `find_elements_by_xpath` an empty list is retrieved so calling anything on the first element won't work.

Change your Xpath expression, so that it matches the element you want to work with. Add some logging or check the size of the list of elements prior to using it.

Comment: I am using Chrome browser so on i am using the  xpath which we get while using the  Inspect element

Comment: Please, edit your question and add a snippet of HTML code with the element you want to locate.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing the error `AttributeError: ("'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'", u'occurred at index 0')` is because, you have used **`find_elements_by_xpath`** method which returns a **`List`**.

We can't invoke **`send_keys`** method on a **`List`** but we can invoke **`send_keys`** method on individual **`WebElement`**.

So the solution will be to use **`find_element_*`** method. You can use either of the following block of code :

- Using **`find_element_by_id`** :

  ```
  paymentNumber = driver.find_element_by_id("search") 
  paymentNumber.send_keys(check_number)
  ```
- Using **`find_element_by_xpath`** :

  ```
  paymentNumber = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search']") 
  paymentNumber.send_keys(check_number)
  ```

Comment: Hi,  I actually have tried it, but some how the script crashes with an error message that it cannot locate the web element

Comment: That means the `xpath` which you have constructed as `'.//*[@id="search"]'`  is incorrect. Try to locate the element properly.

Comment: I am using Chrome browser so on i am using the xpath which we get while using the Inspect element